# AlexNet with PyTorch showing low accuracy after training

Tags: python

I have trained Torchvision AlexNet [with this script](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py).

Now that I load the trained weights and use them for prediction of the val set, I get a very low accuracy.

This is the way I load the weights:

```
alexnet = models.alexnet()
model_path = "model_best.pth.tar"
state_dict = torch.load(model_path,map_location='cpu')
alexnet.load_state_dict(state_dict,strict=False)  
alexnet.eval()
```

I know the rest of my code is correct because it works with the pretrained alexnet on pytorch.

Any suggestion?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the script as far as I can tell.

Can you give some details?
What are you trying to accomplish (Which pictures you use)
How big is your data set?
How many epochs were used for training?

Stuff like that would help us to help you. Therefore some details would be highly appreciated